# Vim+Tmux: How to switch between Tmux Windows and Vim Tab Pages Seamlessly using the Alt Key?

Tags: vimscript, tmux

In Vim I can switch between tab pages with `:tabnext-` to go left and `tabnext+` to go right, simulating the tabs on an IDE. In Tmux I can switch between windows using `<prefix>p` and `<prefix>n` respectively. I'd like to combine these functions: 
I'm trying to remap the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> keys to switch between tab pages in Vim and session windows (which are like tabs) in Tmux when Tmux is available.

**Example**

https://www.codeography.com/2014/06/19/navigating-vim-and-tmux-splits
The plugin 'Vim-Tmux-Navigator' provides a way to seamlessly navigate between Tmux and Vim panes via   for left and right and  and  for up and down. (It looks like when the window number in Vim is maxed it just sends the key commands to Tmux so that there's no need for me to think about which pane in which window I want to switch to.) I'm trying to do the same thing but for switching between Vim Tab pages (created via :tabnew) and Tmux Windows (created via c) (not buffers/windows in Vim or panes in Tmux but tab pages vs Windows).

**What I've tried**

In ~/.vimrc I have:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
    function! TmuxOrTabSwitch(tabcmd, tmuxdir)                                                                      
        let previous_winnr = tabpagenr()
        silent! execute "tabnext " . a:tabcmd
        if previous_winnr == tabpagenr()                                                                         
            call system("tmux select-window -t " . a:tmuxdir)
            redraw!
        endif
    endfunction

    let previous_title = substitute(system("tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}'"), '\n', '', '')
    let &t_ti = "\<Esc>]2;vim\<Esc>\\" . &t_ti
    let &t_te = "\<Esc>]2;". previous_title . "\<Esc>\\" . &t_te

    nnoremap <silent> <A-Left> :call TmuxOrTabSwitch('-', '-')<cr>
    nnoremap <silent> <A-Right> :call TmuxOrTabSwitch('+', '+')<cr>                                                
else
    noremap <A-Left>  :tabprevious<Cr>
    noremap <A-Right> :tabnext<Cr>
endif
```

In ~/.tmux.conf I have:

```
# Move Window left and right
bind -n M-Left run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys M-Left) || tmux select-window -t -"
bind -n M-Right run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys M-Right) || tmux select-window -t +"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work! How can I get this to work the way I described above? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well for one your tmux bindings use Ctrl and not Alt

Comment: It still doesn't work. Good catch, but when I changed it, the alt keys still don't pass anything through to Vim. They do work to change the tab in non-Tmux Vim but only change the Tmux windows in Vim+Tmux, not cycling through the tab pages in Vim.

Comment: You're still using Ctrl in the tmux binds.

Comment: Did you confirm the .tmux.conf file?  If didn't, try: `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: I see now where I left it. I made the correction but unfortunately the problem remains. I did source the conf file again.

Comment: Unfortunately, "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful. What about it doesn't work? Hopefully you've narrowed it down a bit. (FWIW I don't see any issues with the Vim code.)

Comment: Pretty sure I know how this is going wrong. I'll wait for your reply to my previous comment ... it'll help if I have some details on the actual problem, how it fails, anything potentially important or of interest that you found during your debugging.

Comment: When I try to navigate between windows in Tmux, when a window is encountered that has Vim in it, I want it to then start switching between all the tab pages in that instance of Vim. Then, when it is on the last tab page, it would then move on to switching to the next window in Tmux. It's not working that way.

Comment: @Incalculon I just noticed now that you recently replied to my June comment...didn't get a notification. (Might want to add '@BLayer' to future messages to me.) Anyways, you didn't really answer my questions. I already know what you want to happen. I don't know what's _actually_ happening when you hit alt-right in Vim at the last tab. Meanwhile, I'm going to have to recall what I was going to tell you back in late June.

Comment: Another important question: what is the pane title for you vim window? If you don't know what that is hit prefix-key + `:` then enter `display-message -p '#{pane_title}'`